# how to implement an 'or' filter in ReferenceArrayInput

Tags: nestjs, react-admin

please i want to implement an 'or' filter in ReferenceArrayInput
ex. parentId = 1 or null

anyone can help how can i do it

```
            <ReferenceArrayInput
              source="categoriesIds"
              reference="categories"
              label="Categories"
              filter=???
            >
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does your API support a OR operator ?
If not, you can only try the array syntax do to a "or" for a single field: filter:{"myfield": [123,456,789]}